# Thread causing memory leaks

Tags: c, winapi, visual-studio-2013

I have an application that I originally made without threading, and all works fine no memory leaks. I decided to change around the application and added in a thread to handle measurement readings. After adding in the thread, I get a bunch of memory leaks and I cant figure out where they are coming from.

I took out everything from the thread function, so its just an empty function, and I am still getting these leaks...

In the main loop, I added in thread t(Monitor); right before the main message loop.

The Monitor function is now empty
void Monitor { }

And I am getting these memory leaks

```
The thread 0x1d10 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
R6010
- abort() has been called
The thread 0xd64 has exited with code 3 (0x3).
The thread 0x1828 has exited with code 3 (0x3).
The thread 0x1d7c has exited with code 3 (0x3).
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {244} normal block at 0x003A9620, 46 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 1D 00 00 00 1D 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {243} normal block at 0x003A95C8, 23 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 06 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {242} normal block at 0x003A9578, 18 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {241} normal block at 0x003A9520, 22 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 05 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {240} normal block at 0x003A94D0, 18 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {239} normal block at 0x003A9480, 18 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {238} normal block at 0x003A9428, 21 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {237} normal block at 0x003A93D8, 20 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 03 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {236} normal block at 0x003A9380, 21 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {235} normal block at 0x003A9330, 18 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {234} normal block at 0x003A92E0, 18 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {233} normal block at 0x003A9288, 23 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 06 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {232} normal block at 0x003A9230, 22 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 05 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {231} normal block at 0x003A91D8, 22 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 05 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {230} normal block at 0x003A9180, 22 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 05 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {229} normal block at 0x003A9128, 21 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {228} normal block at 0x003A90D0, 21 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {227} normal block at 0x003A9078, 21 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {226} normal block at 0x003A9020, 21 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {225} normal block at 0x003A8FC8, 21 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {224} normal block at 0x003A8F78, 20 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 03 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {223} normal block at 0x003A8F28, 20 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 03 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {222} normal block at 0x003A8ED8, 19 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {221} normal block at 0x003A8E88, 19 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {220} normal block at 0x003A8E38, 19 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {219} normal block at 0x003A8DE8, 19 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {218} normal block at 0x003A8D98, 19 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {217} normal block at 0x003A8D48, 19 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {216} normal block at 0x003A8CF8, 19 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {215} normal block at 0x003A8CA8, 19 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {214} normal block at 0x003A8C58, 19 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {213} normal block at 0x003A8C08, 19 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {212} normal block at 0x003A8BB8, 19 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {211} normal block at 0x003A8B68, 19 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {210} normal block at 0x003A8B18, 19 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {209} normal block at 0x003A8AC8, 19 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {208} normal block at 0x003A8A78, 19 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {207} normal block at 0x003A8A28, 19 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {206} normal block at 0x003A89D8, 18 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {205} normal block at 0x003A8988, 18 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {204} normal block at 0x003A8938, 18 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {203} normal block at 0x003A88E8, 18 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {202} normal block at 0x003A8898, 18 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {201} normal block at 0x003A8848, 18 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {200} normal block at 0x003A87F8, 18 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {199} normal block at 0x003A87A8, 18 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {198} normal block at 0x003A8758, 18 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {197} normal block at 0x003A8708, 18 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {196} normal block at 0x003A86B0, 26 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 09 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {195} normal block at 0x003A8658, 26 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 09 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {194} normal block at 0x003A8600, 26 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 09 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {193} normal block at 0x003A85A8, 26 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 09 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {192} normal block at 0x003A8550, 26 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 09 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {191} normal block at 0x003A84F8, 26 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 09 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {190} normal block at 0x003A84A0, 26 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 09 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {189} normal block at 0x003A8448, 26 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 09 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {188} normal block at 0x003A83F0, 26 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 09 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {187} normal block at 0x003A8398, 26 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 09 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {186} normal block at 0x003A8340, 26 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 09 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {185} normal block at 0x003A82E8, 26 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 09 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {184} normal block at 0x003A8290, 26 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 09 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {183} normal block at 0x003A8238, 26 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 09 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {182} normal block at 0x003A81E0, 26 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 09 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {181} normal block at 0x003A8188, 26 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 09 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {180} normal block at 0x003A8130, 21 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {179} normal block at 0x003A80D8, 21 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {178} normal block at 0x003A8080, 21 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {177} normal block at 0x003A8028, 21 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {176} normal block at 0x003A7FD0, 21 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {175} normal block at 0x003A7F78, 21 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {174} normal block at 0x003A7F20, 21 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {173} normal block at 0x003A7EC8, 21 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {172} normal block at 0x003A7E70, 21 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {171} normal block at 0x003A7E18, 21 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {170} normal block at 0x003A7DC0, 22 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 05 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {169} normal block at 0x003A7D68, 21 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {168} normal block at 0x003A7D10, 22 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 05 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {167} normal block at 0x003A7CB8, 21 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {166} normal block at 0x003A7C60, 21 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {165} normal block at 0x003A7C08, 21 bytes long.
 Data: <x               > 78 C5 E5 0F 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
The program '[7208] Interface Card GUI.exe' has exited with code 3 (0x3).
```

So, I'm guessing I am doing something wrong...but I am not sure what.
Any help would be appreciated!

[Edit] Here is the code I reduced the project to

```
//#include "Variables.h"
//#include "FileFunctions.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include "Tab.h"
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <thread>
//#include <WinSock2.h>
//#include <WS2tcpip.h>

#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

using namespace std;

LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

void Monitor()
{

}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
    _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG );

    int horizontalWindow = 870;
    int verticalWindow = 655;

    /*
    WNDCLASSEX is a structure used during the RegisterClassEx and GetClassInfoEx functions
    cbSize = size of the structure, set to sizeof(WNDCLASSEX)
    style = class styles
    lpfnWndProc = pointer to the window procedure (WinProc function)
    hInstance = handle to the instance that contains the window procedure for the class
    lpszMenuName = pointer to null-terminated string of the window class name
    hIcon and hIconSm used for window icons
    hbrBackground = background of window, could be a bitmap for a picture
    */
    WNDCLASSEX wClass;
    ZeroMemory(&wClass, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wClass.cbClsExtra = NULL;
    wClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wClass.cbWndExtra = NULL;
    wClass.hbrBackground = NULL;//CreateSolidBrush(RGB(240, 240, 240));//(HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wClass.hIcon = (HICON)LoadImage(NULL, "behlmanIcon.ico", IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, LR_LOADFROMFILE);//NULL;
    wClass.hIconSm = (HICON)LoadImage(NULL, "behlmanIcon.ico", IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, LR_LOADFROMFILE);//NULL;
    wClass.hInstance = hInst;
    wClass.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WinProc;
    wClass.lpszClassName = "Window Class";
    wClass.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1);
    wClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    //Register the class using the WNDCLASSEX structure just created
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wClass))
    {
        //if the registeration failed, report error
        int nResult = GetLastError();
        MessageBox(NULL,
            "Window class creation failed\r\n",
            "Window Class Failed",
            MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    //Create a handle to the window
    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
        "Window Class",         //Window class name
        "Windows application",  //Window name (for title bar)
        WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,//WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, //dwStyle for the window
        10,                 //x starting (upper left corner = 0)
        10,                 //y starting (upper left corner = 0)
        horizontalWindow,               //x width
        verticalWindow,                 //y width
        NULL,                   //Handle to the parent window (NULL if parent)
        NULL,                   //Handle to the menu
        hInst,                  //Handle to the instance that contains the window procedure for the class
        NULL);                  //Pointer to a value to be passed to the window through the createstruct

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        //if the handle failed to be created, report error
        int nResult = GetLastError();

        MessageBox(NULL,
            "Window creation failed\r\n",
            "Window Creation Failed",
            MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    //Set the state of the window, to display the window
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nShowCmd);

    MSG msg;
    ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(MSG));

    thread t(Monitor);

    //Window loop
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    //_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {   
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
            break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

[Edit again] Sorry, I didnt realize tab.h was still included...I started going through tab.h and noticed that this variable seems to be causing the memory leak

In tab.c

```
CString openCOM[26] =
{
    "COM0", "COM1", "COM2", "COM3", 
    "COM4", "COM5", "COM6", "COM7", 
    "COM8", "COM9", "\\\\.\\COM10", "\\\\.\\COM11", 
    "\\\\.\\COM12", "\\\\.\\COM13", "\\\\.\\COM14", "\\\\.\\COM15",
    "\\\\.\\COM16", "\\\\.\\COM17", "\\\\.\\COM18", "\\\\.\\COM19",
    "\\\\.\\COM20", "\\\\.\\COM21", "\\\\.\\COM22", "\\\\.\\COM23",
    "\\\\.\\COM24", "\\\\.\\COM25"
};
```

In tab.h
extern CString openCOM[26];

When I comment the CString array out, I no longer get the memory leak

I am confused though, I thought I that cstrings manage their memory themselves, so I dont need a delete[]?

Here is what is left inside tab.c

```
#include "tab.h"
#include "resource.h"

WNDPROC prevWndProc;

HWND hWnd;


CString openCOM[26] =
{
    "COM0", "COM1", "COM2", "COM3", 
    "COM4", "COM5", "COM6", "COM7", 
    "COM8", "COM9", "\\\\.\\COM10", "\\\\.\\COM11", 
    "\\\\.\\COM12", "\\\\.\\COM13", "\\\\.\\COM14", "\\\\.\\COM15",
    "\\\\.\\COM16", "\\\\.\\COM17", "\\\\.\\COM18", "\\\\.\\COM19",
    "\\\\.\\COM20", "\\\\.\\COM21", "\\\\.\\COM22", "\\\\.\\COM23",
    "\\\\.\\COM24", "\\\\.\\COM25"
};
```

And in tab.h

```
#include <afx.h>
#include <Windowsx.h>
#include "commdlg.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <direct.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

extern WNDPROC prevWndProc;

extern HWND hWnd;


extern CString openCOM[26];
```

Comment: Something is missing from the question... Ah, it's the code!

Comment: Oops on my mistake...bear with me then...

Not sure what code you want.

When I comment out thread t(Monitor) from my main loop I dont have the memory leaks...when I have the thread in the code I get the memory leaks.

I original had code in the Monitor function, but I took that all out while I tried to figure out the problem, so right now the Monitor function is empty and I am still getting those memory dumps.

Comment: Well, then, that's perfect. You have already verified, that your threads are leaking resources (or the objects representing threads). Now, take it to the next level: Post the relevant code (ideally an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but I won't hold my breath).

Comment: Please show the code where  you _added in thread t(Monitor); right before the main message loop_.

Comment: Objects at global scope are destroyed at **some** point. This is appears to be after the memory leak detection is executed. As a general rule of thumb: Don't use objects with non-trivial destructors at global scope. Use `const wchar_t* const openCOM[] = { L"COM0", L"COM1", ... };` instead, and construct a `CString`, when you need one.

Comment: Thank you @IInspectable after changing my global CStrings over to wchar_t* I no longer have the memory leaks